# Displaying two values but only the last one is displayed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-table

How can I display two values e.g. `name` and `price`?

In the code below, only the `price` is displayed:

```
{
  Header: 'Price',
  accessor: (row) => row.price,
  Cell: (props) => ({
    props.value !== []
      ? props.value.map(({ name, price }) => (name && price)).join(", ")
      : ''
  })
)
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
props.value.map(({ name, price }) => (`${name} ${price}`)).join(", ")
```

concatenate the strings

```
name + " " + price
```

or

```
`${name} ${price}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your column definition to:

```
{
  Header: 'Price',
  accessor: 'price',
  Cell: ({ row: { values: { name, price } } }) => `${name} ${price}`,
},
```

The `react-table` library's `Cell` callback on a column has access to the row's data i.e. `values`.